# Metaprogramming - r package

Tags: r, metaprogramming, r-package

I have a function within a custom package as shown below:

```
get_data <- function(data, x, y, group) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  y <- enquo(y)
  group <- enquo(group)

  z <- distinct(data,!!x) %>% pull()

  result <- data %>%
    select(!!x, !!y, !!group) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = !!x, values_from = !!y) %>%
    nest(data = z)

  return(result)
}
```

The function works well outside of the package. But does not work when called from the package i.e. the function does not accept data frame column names -  either quoted or unquoted when passed to the arguments x, y, and group. It gives the following error: Error: object 'actual_column_name' not found

I tried modifying the functions using the bang-bang and the embracing operators

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please show exactly how you are calling the function. It seems unlikely this function would work differently inside or outside a function. Normally when you use dplyr functions inside of packages they need to be prefixed by `dplyr::` to pass the package checks. Have you checked your package using `R CMD check` or similar?